# Flash Requirements for Loading XML

Tags: flash

I am noticing a weird behavioral on some pages with flash file that loads XML in IE7 or IE8. If the browser is visible, the XML loads right after the flash. If the browser is minimized, while the load xml happens, it takes like 500 - 900 ms to load the XML. The same issue if its loading an image, say JPG.

Any ideas on what is causing this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally found out the reason:

http://www.kaourantin.net/2010/03/timing-it-right.html

Answer (score 1):

My educated guess is it has nothing to do with Flash, but with the way IE, or perhaps even Windows itself, is implemented: Minimized pages aren't considered as important as fully open windows, so other processes are prioritized.

**Edit**:

I have found several forum threads (like [this one](http://www.codeguru.com/forum/archive/index.php/t-388201.html)) discussing related problems and confirming my theory: Windows reduces thread priority for minimized windows, unless the program uses SetThreadPriority to override this behavior.  This is true for many other programs as well, and it actually makes sense, if you ask me ;)

Comment: Actually confirmed it on Firefox too. Doubt IE issue, but either Windows or Flash

Comment: It's Windows.  I edited my answer, because I found some new information as well.

Comment: So I mocked up with priority levels, and priority class - does not solve the problem.

Comment: I'm curious - how do you mock up a different version of IE?

Comment: Moreover, if the Flash plugin is considered an individual program instance - you'd have to mock that up as well.

Comment: actually I played with the web browser control, since there you can set priority

Comment: Read up on this:http://arstechnica.com/civis/viewtopic.php?f=15&t=318829  and please be fair: I said the plugin's behavior was due to thread priority, but I never said there was a way you could "fix" it. I actually think it is a useful thing not to have your minimized processes hog the CPU.